# ternary operator in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to show and hide HomeCategory objects based on a bool. I have this in place currently:

```
  _isOn ? HomeCategory(0, Icons.check, Colors.blue[800], "Check In", [Task(0, "Check In", true),]) : "",
```

However it throws an error because I am passing an empty string if its turned off. How can I pass it an empty object or hide it? It is a list like so:

```
   _isOn ? HomeCategory(0, Icons.check, Colors.blue[800], "Check In", [Task(0, "Check In", true),]) : "",
    HomeCategory(1, Icons.chat_bubble, Colors.red, "Forums", [ Task(1, "Questions", true),]),
    HomeCategory(2, Icons.star, Colors.blue[200], "Goals", [ Task(2, "Goals", true),]),
    HomeCategory(3, Icons.monetization_on, Colors.orange[700], "Budget", [ Task(3, "Budget", true),]),
    HomeCategory(4, Icons.shopping_basket, Colors.brown[300], "Shopping", [ Task(4, "Items", true),]),
    HomeCategory(5, Icons.calendar_today, Colors.purple[900], "My Day & Calendar", [ Task(4, "Events", false),]),
    HomeCategory(6, Icons.check_circle_outline, Colors.teal[700], "Check Out", [ Task(4, "Tasks", false),]),
    HomeCategory(7, Icons.dock, Colors.grey[700], "Connect", [ Task(4, "Tasks", false),]),
    HomeCategory(8, Icons.local_pharmacy, Colors.green, "My Medication", [ Task(4, "Tasks", false),]),
    HomeCategory(9, Icons.settings, Colors.yellow[800], "Settings", [ Task(4, "Tasks", false),]),
```

Answer (score 19):

You can do this :

```
_isOn ? HomeCategory() : SizedBox()
```

But since it is in a `List<Widget>`, an `if` condition is cleaner :

```
if(_isOn)
    HomeCategory()
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to use ternary operators at all. Ever since Dart 2.3, you can use control statements in collections (i.e. lists and maps) to add things conditionally or in a loop. In your case, you would want to use the conditional syntax:

```dart
Column( // as an example
  children: [
    if (isOn0) HomeCategory(0, Icons.check, Colors.blue[800], "Check In", [Task(0, "Check In", true),]),
    if (isOn1) HomeCategory(1, Icons.chat_bubble, Colors.red, "Forums", [ Task(1, "Questions", true),]),
    if (isOn2) HomeCategory(2, Icons.star, Colors.blue[200], "Goals", [ Task(2, "Goals", true),]),
    ...
  ],
),
```

You could make this even cleaner by combining it with the loop syntax:

```dart
Column(
  children: [
    for (var category in categories)
      if (category.isOn)
        HomeCategory(
          category.id, 
          category.icon, 
          category.color, 
          category.message, 
          category.tasks,
        ),
  ],
),
```

---

EDIT: If you absolutely must have an explicit incrementing index for each `HomeCategory` widget, you can do it like this:

Conditional-Only Syntax:

```dart
int categoryIdx = 0; // declare at the top of the build method
...
Column( // as an example
  children: [
    if (isOn0) HomeCategory(categoryIdx++, Icons.check, Colors.blue[800], "Check In", [Task(0, "Check In", true),]),
    if (isOn1) HomeCategory(categoryIdx++, Icons.chat_bubble, Colors.red, "Forums", [ Task(1, "Questions", true),]),
    if (isOn2) HomeCategory(categoryIdx++, Icons.star, Colors.blue[200], "Goals", [ Task(2, "Goals", true),]),
    ...
  ],
),
```

Conditional + Loop Syntax:

```dart
int categoryIdx = 0; // declare at the top of the build method
...
Column(
  children: [
    for (var category in categories)
      if (category.isOn)
        HomeCategory(
          categoryIdx++, 
          category.icon, 
          category.color, 
          category.message, 
          category.tasks,
        ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: That works, but The ID needs to change according to it being on or off too so I need an else statement or a way to change the id for the next HomeCategory in line.

Comment: @SamCromer That mostly tells me that you really need to rethink your structure. When you're dealing with a list of widgets, the widgets themselves should not have to be responsible for knowing where in the list they are living.

Comment: Unfortunately its not my structure its a Flutter template from flutter awesome that I inherited.

Comment: @SamCromer Flutter awesome templates are just that - templates. You are free to change whatever you want to get the result you are trying for.

Answer (score 1):

I am  utils so:

```
children: [
        if (_selectedIndex == 0) ...[
          DayScreen(),
        ] else if(_selectedIndex == 1)...[
          StatsScreen(),
        ],
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use ternary operator to handle widgets, then in else you can put Container(), or Sizedbox() widget.

```
 condition ? HomeCategory("Check In") : Container()
```

I use container or sizedbox widget everytime, when I dont have anything for else condition, so I pass Container(), as it doesn't occupy any space, or render any style