# character coloring in just one textspan according to index in Flutter

Tags: flutter, richtext, spannablestring

I want apply different color to character in a `textspan` in `Flutter`.

I know `Rich Text` and `TextSpan` method but adding `TextSpan` every part of text that has different color, is not available for my problem, it causes slipping on `Harakas of Arabic`

I would like solve this like `Android Spannable String` index of text.

Is possible in `Flutter`?

like this

```
   SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(st);
   ss.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), 11,25, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly i would say use [Ternary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59691027/ternary-operator-in-flutter) operators

```
   SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(st);
   ss.setSpan(index == foo ? <Other option here> : new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), 11,25, 0 );
```

Comment: Thanks, i asked that this is possible or not in `Flutter`?